# Updating a Nuget Package from Pre-Release to Stable

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

My CI build tool (Bamboo) has been set up to build and deploy my component to NuGet with a -buildxx suffix to indicate it is a pre-release version.

Once we have completed QA, I want this pre-release package to now become the `stable` version and essentially remove the -Suffix.  How can I go about doing this from the NuGet Command Line as I want to automate it via our CI tool in a deployment plan.